# Vue Js- How to call HTTP reuquest when user finished type

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this input box:

```
<b-row>
    <b-col md="3"
        v-for="(header, index) in columns"
        :key="index"
    >
        <b-form-group>
            <b-form-input
                placeholder="Search"
                type="text"
                class="d-inline-block"
                @input="advanceSearch($event, header.field)"
            />
        </b-form-group>                            
    </b-col>
</b-row>
```

When user type something I store the input to `searchString`:

```
advanceSearch(e, field) { 
    this.searchString.push({
        [field] : e
    });
    // http.post().then().catch(); // my http call
},
```

I want call http request when user finished type. But not it seems that every key strong it's callign the HTTP.

Is there any way in VUE JS ?

Comment: What do you mean by "finish typing"? After the user pauses for a while? After the user focuses out?

Comment: @code After the use pauses for a while or click outside

Comment: you are describing the use case for 'debouncing'.  to debounce a function means the function should only run after a certain amount of time has passed since a particular action has stopped (e.g. typing).  general idea is explained [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-debounce-example/).  if you google "vue debounce" you can find some specific vue libraries that can help if you don't want to implement a solution manually yourself.

Comment: @yoduh can you tell me how can I implement it without library?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want the function to be triggered both on idle typing and when a user focuses out.

And un-focused input fires the event `change`, so that should be simple to work with. You can also implement debouncing, amounting to something like the following:

```js
export default {
  advanceSearch(e, field) { /* ... */ },

  // create a custom debounced search
  debouncedSearch(...args) {
    clearTimeout(this.debounceTimeout); // if we set a previous debounce timeout, don't fire it
    this.debounceTimeout = setTimeout(
      // we need to bind a custom `this` value because setTimeout binds `window` by default:
      e => this.advanceSearch.apply(this, args),
      500 // debounce time
    );
  },

  // ...
}
```

For your Vue code, the input should look something like the following. Notice how a `change` listener was added to the component, and that the `input` handler called the `debounce` function instead of directly.

```html
<b-form-input
  placeholder="Search"
  type="text"
  class="d-inline-block"
  @input="debouncedSearch($event, header.field)"
  @change="advanceSearch($event, header.field)"
/>
```

What this code essentially does, is when the user types then clicks out of the input box ("blur"), the HTTP request will fire, or when the user pauses typing for half a second (feel free to change this value), the request will also be sent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me try with this.

Comment: It seems working but when I type something on any input it's called http. it's good but after that If I place the cursor on another input it's calling the http request again. how can I prevent it ?

Comment: @Shibbir that'll get a lot more complicated. You probably would keep a local state of which input is being focused, and when something is changed, check if another input is being focused. Besides that though, 1) is it actually bad if the HTTP request reruns when the user clicks another input, given the fact that you're already setting a timeout, and if the user hasn't typed for 500ms it will run anyways? 2) Do you really need to send an HTTP request when the user blurs the input for the same reason I mentioned?